# Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context

Tags: r, plotly

Estoy creando una función para graficar con plotly pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.
  # Bad:
  list(!!myquosure)

  # Good:
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Tengo otras funciones con códigos parecidos y funcionan sin problema; al quitarle el `enquo()` la función devuelve un plot, sin embargo no grafica según color, no reconoce la variable *z*.

```
data(mtcars)

f4 <- function(z){
  require("dplyr")
  require("lazyeval")
  require("reshape")
   z <- as_name(z)
  
  
  plt <- mtcars %>% 
    select_(~disp, ~hp, ~mpg, all_of(~z)) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(mpg, z)) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>%
    arrange_(~mpg)
  
  
  plt1 <- gather(plt, key='variable', value = 'Monto', disp, hp) %>%
    mutate(catvar=paste(mpg, variable, sep='_'))
  
  
  z <- enquo(z)  
  
  
  fig <- plot_ly(plt1)
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x= ~catvar, y= ~Monto, color=!!z,
                           type = 'bar', colors= 'BrBG',
                           showlegend = TRUE,
                           hoverinfo = "text",
                           text = ~paste(catvar, '\n Monto:', Monto, 'MM USD \n ', z)) %>%
    layout(barmode = "stack") %>%
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title='MM USD', rangemode='tozero',side = 'left',  overlaying = "y2", title = 'MM de USD', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
  
  return(fig)
  
}

f4('carb')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta versión funciona (o al menos eso creo). El problema es que no sé como ni por qué funciona.

Por lo que entendí el problema es que `plotly` tiene su propio esquema de evaluación no estándar (las fórmulas de un solo lado con `~x`), que está bastante mal documentado. Tidyeval usa otro esquema (casi siempre `enquo(x); !!x`) y estos dos se llevan. Sin embargo si en lugar de usar `!!` se usa `.data[[nombre_a_evaluar_disponible_en_entorno]]` anda. `tidyeval` funciona de maneras misteriosas.

```
data(mtcars)

f4 <- function(z){
  require("dplyr")
  require("lazyeval")
  require("reshape")
  z <- as_name(z)
  
  
  plt <- mtcars %>% 
    select_(~disp, ~hp, ~mpg, all_of(~z)) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(mpg, z)) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>%
    arrange_(~mpg)
  
  
  plt1 <- gather(plt, key='variable', value = 'Monto', disp, hp) %>%
    mutate(catvar=paste(mpg, variable, sep='_'))
  
  
  #z <- enquo(z) #No es necesario el enquo 
  
  
  fig <- plot_ly(plt1)
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x= ~catvar, y= ~Monto, 
                           color=~.data[[z]],  #Acá uso el operado .data[[]]
                           type = 'bar', colors= 'BrBG',
                           showlegend = TRUE,
                           hoverinfo = "text",
                           text = ~paste(catvar, '\n Monto:', Monto, 'MM USD \n ', z)) %>%
    layout(barmode = "stack") %>%
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title='MM USD', rangemode='tozero',side = 'left',  overlaying = "y2", title = 'MM de USD', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
  
  return(fig)
  
}

f4('carb')
```

Ojalá resuelva tu problema.

> Nota aparte: Si es un código importante y que vas a seguir usando quizás valga mucho la pena que lo refactorees desde cero. Aunque funciona se me hace bastante complicado de entender y mantener.